# Writing a combo system

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

How could one write an easy-to-maintain combo system of at least 3 items in C#?

Example: We play from our deck

```
Card A
Card B
Card C
```

This does some super awesome combo called Ultra Card Combo (whatever). Now this is easy to write if the order matters:

```
if(cards[0] == "Card A"){
   if(cards[1] == "Card B" && cards[2] == "Card C"){
     doComboThingy();
   }
}
```

But now we need all 6 combinations

```
A / B / C
A / C/ B
B / A / C
B / C / A
C / B / A
C / A / B
```

I think this has probably been tackled 100000s of times, and maybe there's an algorithm everyone knows about. But I cannot find it!

Thanks.

Comment: You could just sort the list of played cards, then you only have to check A / B / C.

Comment: I think is not just a matter of sorting... but the nested if's it needs to accomplish it and how complex it turns to be as he needs other combo combinations.
The beauty of using LINQ is that it kind of cut through your intention: you have a collection and you want to know if it matches with other collection regardless of the order.

Also, I don't know if cards is expected to have only 3 elements. If it has more than 3, and you have to find all 3 combo cards in a bigger collection, it increases the complexity even more.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use LINQ:

Considering you have a collection of combo cards

```
var comboCards = new [] {"Card A", "Card B", "Card C"};

if(cards.Intersect(comboCards).Count() == comboCards.Count())
```

That means you're taking your cards collection and getting the intersect items with the combo cards. The result should have the same count of your combo cards.

Comment: That sounds super easy. But I have read there are problems with Linq and IOS which I am developing for. Any idea if that is still true?

Comment: I think it worthes a test. I just found a lot of issues regarding to LINQ in iOS but the all are before 2013, and even back then it seems people were not sure about it.
In case it is still a problem, it seems that recently someone did solve it with this: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-linq-to-ios.274088/

Comment: @dmyoko I certainly had the same issues back in 2014, but with IL2CPP released they might already be over.